# Spring Boot GCP: "Google Credentials" Exception When Deploying PubSub Application to App Engine Standard Environment

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am attempting to deploy a Spring Boot application to GCP's App Engine Standard environment. The application is able to receive published messages from PubSub while running locally on my dev machine. I have configured the application to authenticate with service credentials via the `$GOOGLE_APPLICATON_CREDENTIALS` environment variable.

However, when I attempt to publish this application to App Engine, and then subsequently tail the logs (via `gcloud app logs tail -s test-app-service`), I see the following error:  `Factory method 'googleCredentials' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/app-engine-service-creds.json (No such file or directory)`

And the application fails to start. This happens both when I run the gcloud deploy CLI command:

```
gcloud app deploy build/libs/test-app-*.jar --appyaml=src/main/appengine/app.yaml
```

as well as the Gradle GCP plugin task:

```
./gradlew appengineDeploy
```

This error also occurs when I include the JSON key file in `src/main/resources` and reference it in my application.yaml file with the `spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location` argument.

There is shockingly little documentation about actually *deploying* Spring Boot applications to App Engine, and I am out of ideas here.

**app.yaml:**

```
runtime: java11
service: "test-app-service"
env_variables:
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "gcp"
```

Any and all suggestions here would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit**
Additional (potentially) relevant files:
`application-gcp.yaml`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gcp:
      project-id: "my-project"
```

`build.gradle.kts`

```
import com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.appyaml.AppEngineAppYamlExtension
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:2.2.0")
    }
}

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.1"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.10.RELEASE"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.4.21"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.21"
}

group = "com.myGroup"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

if (project.hasProperty("projVersion")) {
    project.version = project.properties["projVersion"]!!
} else {
    project.version = "1.0.0"
//  throw Exception("Project Version must be passed in ex.   ./gradlew clean build -PprojVersion=1.0.0")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
}

apply {
    plugin("com.google.cloud.tools.appengine")
}

// exclude the app-engine-service-creds
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            exclude("app-engine-service-creds.json")
        }
    }
}

extra["springCloudGcpVersion"] = "2.0.0-RC2"
extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2020.0.0-M6"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive")
    implementation("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.12.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.amshove.kluent:kluent:1.64")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-test")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:${property("springCloudGcpVersion")}")
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

configure<AppEngineAppYamlExtension> {
    deploy {
        projectId = "my-project"
        version = "GCLOUD_CONFIG"
        stopPreviousVersion = true // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to deploy by commenting the resource line `spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location`?

Comment: I did, yes. This fails when I attempt to deploy with the credentials location specified as a property, and without

Comment: Do you have a minimal code sample to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere added the application-gcp.yaml and build.gradle.kts files. Is there anything else, implementation-wise, you would find relevant? Thank you for helping with this!

Comment: And you never use cred file in your code? It fails at startup, correct?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere correct, it fails at startup, both when I include the credentials file in the resources directory, and when I exclude it from the build.

Comment: Did you try running `gcloud auth application-default login` to set the authentication variables? The application will look for these credentials automatically if GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is not set.

Comment: Please see my "solution" to this issue below. Thank you both for your help and advice on this, though. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the tailed logs returned from the `gcloud app logs tail -s {service-name}` command can be a bit of a red herring. Although I was deploying a new version of the application, and all traffic is 100% directed toward this new instance, the app does not "startup" until it receives a request. For reasons that I still do not fully understand, the logs were tailing a *very* stale version of the application (and I'm not the only one who has been confounded by this, obviously: ["gcloud app logs tail" shows week old data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477818/gcloud-app-logs-tail-shows-week-old-data)).

In reality, the app was not experiencing any credentials issues after all, but was merely running out of memory on startup, and thus, I was unable to verify that the messages had been pulled successfully from PubSub by my applcation.

I fixed this by add the following parameter to my `app.yaml` filed:
`instance_class: f4`

The problem has since resolved itself.